# WordPress Admin Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm wondering how I can make a plugin to output some data via the admin panel.
Just to get me going what code would make a page in the admin panel (for only administrators) to display time()?

Answer (score 11):

It's actually very easy, you only need two things:

1. [One of many tutorials on writing a Wordpress plugin](http://ditio.net/2007/08/09/how-to-create-wordpress-plugin-from-a-scratch/). Plugins subscribe to actions (amongst other things) and can emit HTML when an action is triggered by the Wordpress engine.
2. The [list on the Wordpress codex of actions to which plugins can subscribe](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) to trigger their own code. Adding actions is defined in that tutorial. Specifically you want the [administrative actions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Administrative_Actions). e.g.: the `admin_footer` action will cause your plugin's output to be displayed in the footer of the admin page. There's a wide range of actions for all kinds of situations and conditions.

The PHP `date()` function will give you the current time, so you just need to write a function in your plugin that does `echo date()`, and then use `add_action` to get your PHP function executed in response to the appropriate Wordpress action.

So to make it completely clear, your plugin code would look like this (not tested!):

```
/*
Plugin Name: Admin Date Displayer
Plugin URI: http://example.com/
Description: Displays the current datetime on the admin page
Author: Stewart
Version: 1.0
Author URI: http://bolidian.com/
*/

function display_date()
{
    echo date();
}

add_action('admin_footer', 'display_date');
```